# nginx rewrite url from one site to subdomain in other site?

Tags: nginx, web-server

How can I rewrite or redirect url ***domain.com/auth$*** to ***subdomain.domain.com/auth$*** ?

I have tried to match url but no effect. simple redirec 301 doesnt work.

Thanks!

Just got a solution, add the following to nginx config file:

rewrite ^/auth(.*) https://subdomain.$host/auth$1 permanent;

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just got a solution, add the following to nginx config file:

rewrite ^/auth(.*) https://subdomain.$host/auth$1 permanent;